# Issue precision CGAL's Delaunay triangulation

Tags: cgal

I am having an issue that is probably due to the mismatch between the precision of a double and the infinite precision given in CGAL, but I cannot seem to solve it, and do not see anyway to set a tolerance.

I input a set of points (initially the locations are doubles).

When the points are aligned horizontally on the upper part (and only happens there) I sometimes (not always) get an issue of too many triangles (with a really small area, almost 0) being generated: see image

(*notice in the upper section, how there is a line that seems to be thicker than the rest, because there are at least 3 triangles there).

[image]

This is what I am doing in my code, I tried to set the kernel to handle the imprecision of doubles:

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>    CK;
typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CK>         K;
//typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Point_2  Point;
typedef K::Segment_2  Segment;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K> Polygon_2;    
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned long, K> Vb2;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb2,Fb> Tds2;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,Tds2> Delaunay;

std::vector<std::vector<long> > Geometry::delaunay(std::vector<double> xs,std::vector<double> ys){
std::vector<Point> points;
std::vector<unsigned long> indices;

points.resize(xs.size());
indices.resize(xs.size());
for(long i=0;i<xs.size();i++){
    indices[i]=i;
    points[i]=Point(xs[i],ys[i]);
}
std::vector<long> idAs;
std::vector<long> idBs;

Delaunay dt;
dt.insert( boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple( points.begin(),indices.begin() )),boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple( points.end(),indices.end() ) )  );

for(Delaunay::Finite_edges_iterator it = dt.finite_edges_begin(); it != dt.finite_edges_end(); ++it)
{
    Delaunay::Edge e=*it;
    long i1= e.first->vertex( (e.second+1)%3 )->info();
    long i2= e.first->vertex( (e.second+2)%3 )->info();
    idAs.push_back(i1);
    idBs.push_back(i2);
}
std::vector<std::vector<long> > result;
result.resize(2);
result[0]=(idAs);
result[1]=(idBs);

return result;
}
```

I am completely new to CGAL, and this code is something that I have been able to put together after a lot of looking up in web pages in the last 2 days. So if there is something else that might be improved, please, do not hesitate to mention it, the sintaxis of CGAL is not really straightforward.

*the code works perfectly for random points, and 70% of the times even for points that are aligned, but the other 30% worries me.

THE QUESTION IS, how can I set a tolerance, so CGAL does not generate triangles on top of points that are almost almost aligned??, or is there a better kernel for this? (as you see I tried also the Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel, but it is even worst).

Comment: How is Epick worse? It should give the same result. CGAL is producing exactly what it is meant to produce, that is a triangulation. When you have 3 almost aligned points on the convex hull, cgal first determines if the middle point is inside or outside (possibly through symbolic perturbation), and if it is inside, then we are forced to produce a thin triangle. If you don't care about the convex hull not being quite convex, you could add a few (3+) dummy points very far, surrounding your real points, then ignore all the cells involving dummy points.

Comment: Well, you are right that this is the perfectly correct geometric result, but that is why I am talking about setting up a tolerance, my issue is that later on I transform this into a graph, and at a later step I might want to detect the faces to calculate the dual graph, which I do by calculating angles using atan2. The atan2 does not get the angles perfectly right when they are so similar, so my face detection gets messed up. I know that if I knew enough of CGAL and I keep the triangulation object alife then I could do the face detection in CGAL, but the structure of my code is very complex.

Comment: CGAL has a Voronoi_2 package to handle the dual graph, IIRC. Adding dummy points or ignoring the skinny triangles on the convex hull (à la alpha-shape) seem like the easiest ways to work around your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But the operation of the dual for me is independent from the delaunay or any geometry, it is a general operation for graphs embedded into a space. Unfortunately, I need to keep most of my classes separated from CGAL, because I sometimes calculate things in a cluster of computers which do not have CGAL, so the operations with CGAL are meant only for my computer. The structure of my code is complex, I have around 100 classes, sometimes I call C++ from R, sometimes I run a code based on part of the classes in the cluster.

Comment: Actually, your second option, (à la alpha-shape), might be a good option, I am currently trying something else but I will for sure give it a try, thank you very much.

Comment: Regarding the Voronoi. The centres of the faces are not guaranteed to be within the face, which can generate strange issues for me, that and that for me the dual is a different operation is why I am not trying it.